# CSF firewal - how does csf.allow work?

Tags: firewall

In my csf.allow file I have (something like):

```
98.765.43.21
tcp:in:d=20:s=12.345.67.89
tcp:in:d=21:s=12.345.67.89
```

Am I right in thinking that this will
1) always allow any service for 98.765.43.21
2) deny incoming FTP connections on tcp ports for all IPs except 12.345.67.89 ?

The first IP (98.765.43.21) does not seem to deny anything, while the second two definitions seems to deny all other IPs from accessing those specified services. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right, some examples taken from the readme.txt:

```
# TCP connections inbound to port 3306 from IP 11.22.33.44
tcp:in:d=3306:s=11.22.33.44

# TCP connections outbound to port 22 on IP 11.22.33.44
tcp:out:d=22:d=11.22.33.44

If omitted, the default protocol is set to "tcp", the default connection
direction is set to "in"
```

Comment: I enter just an ip address on a single line and it is allowed but all other ips are too, so nothing is denied. But if I put
tcp:in:d=20:s=12.345.67.89
this will deny that specific port to all ips except the one specified. Why are all ips not denied by entering my first ip address on single line?

Comment: @MOFlint: well, can't check now by I think that csf.allow OVERRIDES other blocks, so you should probably "block all" (in csf.deny or by other means) and then only what's inside csf.allow is allowed...

Comment: In the csf config file I had ports 20,21 OMITTED from "TCP_IN" - and so csf.allow just overrides this directive for the named IPs and allows them to use those ports.